# Reference a native app from a responsive website?

Tags: html, ios, responsive-design, app-store

I'm at a loss and have exhausted my search engine fu.

How do you refer to the linking that allows you to reference your native app in the AppStore (or Google Play) from your responsive website?

If user doesn't have your native app but they visit your website you often see a link to the native app above the page that you can usually dismiss (though this Instagram example I just created doesn't appear to let you dismiss it).

[image]

How is this handled?

**Edit**: Actually, here's a better example (I happen to have app installed but it appears regardless)

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html
via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130901/link-to-app-store-widget-for-mobile-website

Comment: That's it!!! Thanks. You can add it as an answer or I'll delete this stupid question.  Though still curious if there's an Android equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's easy on iOS [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/promoting_apps_with_smart_app_banners)
via [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130901/link-to-app-store-widget-for-mobile-website)

The Android equivalent is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168706/creating-an-android-smart-app-banner) I haven't tried it personally.

Comment: Thanks! I looked for this in iOS HIG but, alas, the Safari Web Content Guide was the spot.